# Compiler can't find SFML/Graphics.hpp, but it is added to includedirs

Tags: c++, game-engine, sfml, premake

I have started working on a game engine of which you can find the source code at https://github.com/SapphireOmega/MarbleEngine. I set my project up using premake5. I tried to use sfml, but on both windows and linux (haven't tried macos) I get an error saying "SFML/Graphics.hpp" not found.

I have tried many different things, but none of them succeded. Currently I have the sfml files in MarbleEngine/vendor//SFML and have added the path to includedirs in both the MarbleEngine project, which is the game engine itself, and the Sandbox project, which is an example project, but still for some reason it won't find it.

Below you can find an example of a line that adds the path to the includedirs

```lua
includedirs { "%{prj.name}/vendor/linux/SFML/include" }
```

I reccomend you look at the github repo for the full project and code

Visual Studio gives the following error message:
`Cannot open include file: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp': No such file or directory`

I expected it to just work and compile, since the path to SFML/Graphics.hpp is in the includedirs, but instead it can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the .dll 's you are using to the project. Easiest is to add them where the .exe is. Have you done/tried that?